# What's the protocol that makes a browser downloads instead of launching an app for a file?

Tags: download, html, html5

An `<a href="....mp3">` link would make most browsers launch the default media player to open the mp3 file.

`<a href="...mp3" download>` would make some Html5 browsers download, ie saves, the mp3 file instead.

I checked the traffic and both `a` tags send `Content-Type:audio/mpeg`. Does the browser look at the `download` attribute and behave accordingly?

IE, even the latest version, does not honor that `download` attribute. Is there another method that would work for all browsers?

---

Additional info: my requirement came about because some phone users complained that they do not have an option of downloading the file for listening offline.

I was aware that that PC browsers usually can usually right click and save a file in a link. I thought I could do the same on a phone browser (Android Chrome) by touch and hold, but was disappointed.

So it seems that I would have to implement two links, one to navigate and one to download, if I don't want to add code to output different Html based on browser type.

Comment: IE is not the only browser which doesn't support the anchor `download` attribute. See [Download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute)

Comment: [so] duplicate: [any clean ways to dowload files like html5 download attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16331666)

Comment: Is it your server?

Comment: It is an IIS hosted on 1and1, and the site is an ASP.NET application.

Comment: If you can modify code on the server then see [How to implement Content-Disposition: attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8875949) for the proper solution.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the "traditional" way to get a browser to download.